# How to get Facebook like live feeds in our iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook, feed, live

Android has a third party library called volley for this. Is there anything which we can use to achieve this and i want to display the same live feed structure in my iOS app but with a few changes :

1) I want images, videos or simple texts whenever in the image view of the Facebook feed and this should come from the server.

2) In the middle of the feeds i want simple feed of an image or a text.

I have to achieve this dynamically !!